# Create a service which always runs in background even if app kills

Tags: android, performance, android-activity, android-service, alarmmanager

I want to create a service that always runs in background. I made several attempts but my service always stops when I swipe up the app from Recent Apps. I tried the solutions available by running service in separate process.

I also tried to return START_STICKY from service's onStartCommand but that too didn't work out. Please refer the sample image for services running always in background. Even if whatsApp is not in my recent Apps but service not closed.

Please help me. I am struggling in this for long time.

Here is my code

```
        public class service extends Service
{
    private static final String TAG = "MyService";
    public static String MAIN_ACTION = "main";
    public static String PREV_ACTION = "prev";
    public static String PLAY_ACTION = "play";
    public static String NEXT_ACTION = "next";
    public static int FOREGROUND_SERVICE = 101;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");
        Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


    public void onCreate() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Service created");
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onStart");
    Log.d(TAG, "Service started");
    processIntent(intent);

    Thread readerThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            while(true) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Thread present");
                try {
                    // thread to sleep for 1000 milliseconds
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(e);
                }
            }
        }
    });
    readerThread.start();
    }

}
```

and I am calling it from my activity like this

```
  Intent i = new Intent(this, service.class);
  startService(i);
```

Service get started when app runs and I see the Service running in Running Apps with 1 process and 1 service but when I swipe out the app both process and service get killed

Thanks

[image: This is what I am trying to do]

Comment: How did you start your service when using START_STICKY? It would help if you attach some code.

Comment: Try to set high priority to your `Service`.

Comment: use WakefulIntentService ..

Comment: Your service isn't *doing* anything. If you add a Thread to it and start that, and foreground the service according to the docs, then swiping the app away will not terminate the Service.

Comment: @tristan2468 I have updated the code and added a timer task in service but then to its closing on swapping the app. Please tell me where I am going wrong. I thought it would be a easy task as many apps do that but I stuck on it for long time. Thanks

Comment: @  Subhalaxmi Nayak I don't want to overcomplicate things. I am trying to make a service that always runs even without activity just like whatsapp app is doing as shown. I don't know how WakefulIntentService helps here. Can you please eloborate. Thanks

Comment: I have made service like this which runs on background even when the app is closed or even removed from recent apps list. All I did was return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);         which means it returns  START_STICKY. Try printing a toast message when the service is destroyed or created. Use logcats to see what callbacks are being used.

Comment: @user2430771 I already checked the callbacks. Service onDestroy is not called but it print W/ActivityManager( 1160): 

Scheduling restart of crashed service com.net.GCMNotificationIntentService

Force stopping service ServiceRecord{44aa4aa0 u0 com.net.GCMNotificationIntentService}

Comment: Also I am returning START_STICKY from onStartCommand()

Comment: @tristan2468 I have updated my code. Please see it. I am getting this message.            Scheduling restart of crashed service                Force stopping service ServiceRecord         in logcat

Comment: @user3265443 I cannot find any return statement in your onStartCommand(), use return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);